# Is there a holy grail of power line connectors and cords?

Tags: power

After asking about why we don't use 2.5 mm and 3.5 mm for power [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/518919/is-there-any-reason-why-we-don-t-supply-power-to-a-2-5-or-3-5-jack/) it sounds like cables and connectors are optimized and there is not a search for a holy grail of connectors.

Does anyone fantasize about better connectors or a universal connector or cord or has that been achieved?

For example, when one goes about inventing, does one think, "Anything I need to do can be accomplished with a USB-C or a 3 prong power cord".

FYI I realize this may sound like an opinion based question but I'm asking from the technical side.

If connector ABC has technical problems then maybe it's not an opinion that a better connector is desirable and sought after, much like the metaphor of `unobtanium`.

Or how with USB A no matter what side you inserted it in it was always upside down and you had to flip it over. Someone must have thought, "I wish there was a cable that didn't have this issue."

So in the field do people still wish for better connectors or power cables? Is there an equivalent "unobtainium"?

Comment: A soft switch is far better than a dry contact which creates arc currents on contact and arc voltages from inductive disconnect heating up the contact or burning the plating.  even lightning connectors burn out from black pitting marks on the gold flash plating when charging on contact the input caps on an iPad.  That has to do with Ic=CdV/dt or the contact resistance near 0 =dV/dI for a zero time contact

Comment: as you can trivially see by the fact that we're still seeing new connectors for new purposes, and new connectors for old purposes appear, yeah, your question **is** an opinion question (or not a question at all). Obviously, we all want the best connector for any given purpose. But it also can't cost 4000€, weigh 22 kg, be as large as a shoebox and restricted from being exported. *As with anything in engineering*: **There is no universal best. It all depends on purpose and restrictions.**

Comment: Not a bad question. AC connectors are well established, and for very low power, barrel jacks are everywhere, but there isn't really a widely established standard for 12 or 24V at (say) 10 to 20A, or even higher, that could be useful for LV systems. (Except the detestable clunky car cigar lighter). There's Andersons, which are in-line, not chassis or wall mounting. I use XLRs (which are rated for surprisingly high current) but I'd jump on a widely used standard if there was one.

Comment: @BrianDrummond is that the case? 12V and 20V high-amperage connectors are pretty standardized in car / trailer connections. If you like XLR, powercon might be of interest too (but that's used for mains voltage, so, um, noooo). I can fully recommend Speakon, high amperage, plenty of voltage safety for 24V, relatively cheap, multi-sourcable, more robust than XLR. The robotics field has a few connectors that might become canonical.

Comment: @BrianDrummond and for really high amperage DC, there *is* a widely adopted and tested standard: SAE J1772, DC Level 1 & 2. Car charging connector!

Comment: @Marcus Müller, really large? There is a bit of a gap between SAE J17722 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/509972/what-is-the-largest-electrical-connector-in-the-world.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If every appliance looks like a trailer, sure...  though even there I've seen adapters between different trailer connectors. There's also a series of through-deck connectors on boats, that look almost hand-machined. Thanks for the Speakon suggestion ... poss worth looking into. I think your " ... might become canonical" supports my view. I think it may become important as small DC systems proliferate for lighting and small appliances, with solar/battery power, and inverters/grid restricted to high power applications (heat, cooking, laundry)

Comment: @CharlesCowie is a game of *Top Trumps: Cables* that is among the hard-to-beat cards

Comment: @BrianDrummond well, copper isn't getting cheaper anytime soon, but my guess is that step-down regulators might, so I think for the medium-power market (larger TVs, illumination) some 120V/220V will remain the standard for a long time to come; but honestly, my crystal ball is very foggy these days.

Comment: There exist connector housings that allow you to build whatever connections you want from modules. You can build a connector with for example mains supply, gigabit ethernet and pneumatics if you want. So if money is not a limiting factor, you can build whatever holy grail you want.

Comment: @CharlesCowie, Brian, also, <= 100V DC "proper" connectors, maybe go for IEC 60309-2 "yellow" 5 pin connectors.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I just learned of the existence of IEC 60906-3:1994 "safe extra-low voltage DC connectors", good for up to 16 A.

Comment: I could say what connector form factor I like best, and I could say what form factor I would choose for a particular task (it depends on current, voltage, number of conductors, environmental conditions, make/break cycles, price, and any number of other things), and they will not always be the same, nor will they be the same you would get asking someone else. There's no best option.

Comment: downvote ... `Does anyone fantasize ....?` and `do people still wish for ...?` are not technical questions about electronics

Comment: @jsotola I was considering the history of the washing machine. It used to plug in to the light socket, it used to maim people and in general it was not what it is to today. Maybe it’s not normal where you’re from but I know a lot of people who have wished for technical things that would make their life better. I wished for things like wireless power sometimes when the cord wouldn’t reach.

Answer (score 2):

Physical constraints, cost, current / voltage demand, insertion / disconnect, vibration, environment and safety requirements all factor in to the power connector choice. There’s no one connector that satisfies all of these.

You can broadly divide power connectors into two categories: SELV (Safety Extra-Low Voltage) which pose little or no shock hazard, and Line for anything that doesn’t fit into the SELV category. Generally, 52-60V is the SELV cutoff. Anything above that voltage isn’t considered touch-safe.

USB-C tries to be all those things limited to SELV voltage, but won’t cut it for applications above 60V. And it’s kind of fragile and expensive in my opinion. Nevertheless it’s gaining traction as a go-to for consumer device power delivery. Automotive? Industrial? Nope. Too fragile, though weather-tight and even waterproof USB-A connectors exist.

The magnetic connector Apple used on Macs was kind of cool, but probably costly because Apple. Plus, magnets wiping out stripes on cards.

For line, the 3-prong ‘kettle cord’ works as a nearly universal solution, though it’s too bulky for some gear.

For appliances that don’t need ground and are limited in power, the 2-line type works well. That said, devices in this power class (50W or so) could also use USB-C.

So no one universal connector, but relatively few to choose from.

Comment: There's also the [IEC 603020 C5 'Mickey Mouse'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C5) connector, which is smaller than the C13 kettle, whilst still being grounded